# React Component: Foundation Modal (Reveal) won't open

Tags: reactjs, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

So I've just started learning React and Redux, so I apologize if this is a very noobish question. But I've emptied my Google quote, and can't find anything that helps me.

My problem is: I work on a site with React, Redux, and Foundation 6. One of my React components have a link, that when clicked, should open a Modal with a specific warning for that link. So I've created a component with my modal markup:

**ComponentModal.js:**

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
const Modal = () => (
  <div className="reveal" id="exampleModal1" data-reveal>
    <h1>Awesome. I Have It.</h1>
  </div>
);

export default Modal;
```

The component with a link renders some stuff, but basically have a

`<a data-open="exampleModal1">Click me for a modal</a>`

tag in it's render.

And although inspecting the page confirms that the markup for the modal exists, nothing happens when i click the link.
If I move the popup from the component, and into the DOM, the link works.
Some trial and error shows me, that if i manually run `$(document).foundation();` in the console when ComponentModal is rendered, the popup works as intended.

So my question is kinda two questions:
1. How do I, in Redux, run `$(document).foundation();` when my ComponentModal is done rendering? Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't have the `componentDidMount()` method available to me, where it might make sense to make that call?
2. Is this a totally wrong way to go about it?

Hope it's not too confusing and not too dumb a question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, this question/solution has nothing to do with REDUX!

The problem is that you're trying to use React AND Jquery to make your page do cool things.

You should really choose one or the other.

`$(document).foundation()` is a Jquery library.

Instead you should use something like [React Foundation](http://webrafter.com/opensource/react-foundation-apps/modal) which removes the jquery dependency and gives you foundation components built with react.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of jQuery, but I do like Foundation. My page is not a single page react app, so Foundation is used for styling some of the elements around the more static parts of the page. I would very much like not to change that. But maybe I should look for alternatives for the modal part.
But my REDUX question still stands - is the componentDidMount method available and would it be the right place? Some colleague just told me it was, and I should use that, so I'll give it a try.

Comment: No `componentDidMount` is *not* from redux! its part of react! 

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html

Comment: you have to change the modal to a Component instead of a function. and yes you will have access to react `componentDidMount`

Comment: redux is only reducers, actions, stores. Has nothing to do with component lifecycle  https://github.com/reactjs/redux#the-gist

Answer (score 0):

You can do `$(document).foundation()` in React inside `componentDidMount` of the component that has the reval modal or better yet You can do this inside componentDidMount of the top most partent in your app.

`componentDidMount` in React runs once after all the DOM nodes related to that component is mounted. What `$(document).foundation()` does, if it runs inside `componentDidMount`, is that it binds event handlers on the elements that have foundation realated attributes like data-dropdown or data-reveal.

```
componentDidMount() {
  $(document).foundation();
}
```